# Django REST authentication with React/ Redux

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, redux, django-rest-framework

I am building a web app with a Django backend and React/Redux frontend running on separate servers. I have begun to try and start working on authentication and I cannot find a tutorial that suits my needs. Every tutorial either uses deprecated modules like drf-jwt (as opposed to simple-jwt) or has a simple mono-server that houses both the backend and the frontend in one directory. The former is useless and I do not want to do the latter as I like having the two separate servers for when I move on to deployment. Now can someone direct me to a good source of knowledge for getting this done? It doesn't have to be a tutorial it can be anything. I am really lost and I do not know how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 3rd party packages `djoser`: Provides a set of views to handle basic actions such as registration, login, logout, password reset and account activation. for more information: https://pypi.org/project/djoser/

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem. I am trying to learn how Django, React and Redux play together in regards to authentication. This is just another library that convolutes the process for me.

Comment: then you can use your custom authentication systems using jwt-token bases. for more information: https://github.com/satyajitbarik/eCommerce-and-TourTravel-Backend/blob/master/account/api/serializers.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm using token authentication from [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) so, after a login/password verification, the token on response can be used on any DRF endpoint.